# Does AsyncFunction often run asynchronously?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, ecmascript-2017

I am writing a module to intake and run some [koa](https://koajs.com/)-like middlewares. The following code snippet demos how it works.

```js
function _createNext(it) {
  return async () => {
    const result = it.next()
    if (!result.done) {
      const middleware = result.value
      const next = _createNext(it)
      await middleware(next)
    }
  }
}

function _createMiddleware(x) {
  return async (next) => {
    console.log(`start: ${x}`)
    await next()
    console.log(`end: ${x}`)
  }
}

const arr = [
  _createMiddleware('a'),
  _createMiddleware('b'),
  _createMiddleware('c'),
]

const arrIterator = arr[Symbol.iterator]()
const next = _createNext(arrIterator)

console.log('1st Line')
next()  // <--- (*)
console.log('2nd Line')
```

I expected that the "2nd Line" should print right after the "1st Line", because I didn't `await` the `next()` on **Line (*)** and `next()` should be asynchronous. Instead, it seems to me that `next()` runs synchronously.

```
// ACTUAL result
1st Line
start: a
start: b
start: c
2nd Line
end: c
end: b
end: a

// EXPECTED result
1st Line
2nd Line
start: a
start: b
start: c
end: c
end: b
end: a
```

Then I tried to update the `_createNext` function as follow, things work perfectly.

```js
function _createNext(it) {
  return () => {
    return Promise.resolve()
      .then(async () => {
        const result = it.next()
        if (!result.done) {
          const middleware = result.value
          const next = _createNext(it)
          await middleware(next)
        }
      })
  }
}

function _createMiddleware(x) {
  return async (next) => {
    console.log(`start: ${x}`)
    await next()
    console.log(`end: ${x}`)
  }
}

const arr = [
  _createMiddleware('a'),
  _createMiddleware('b'),
  _createMiddleware('c'),
]

const arrIterator = arr[Symbol.iterator]()
const next = _createNext(arrIterator)

console.log('1st Line')
next()  // <--- (*)
console.log('2nd Line')
```

I am confused about what's wrong with the first code snippet. I thought AsyncFunction behaves very much like a Promise in which the function content should always run in the nextTick.

Could someone help to explain? Thanks a lot.

Comment: The function content in `AsyncFunction` runs immediately.  There's no wait for a new tick.  The promise it returns will wait for the next tick before calling `.then()` no matter when the promise is resolved.  FYI, there's no wait for the next tick when running the Promise executor callback either so perhaps you just misunderstood that.